# Using Rcpp for faster extraction and summary of lm output

Tags: r, rcpp, tidy, broom

I'm trying to speed up extraction from R's summary lm object when contained in an extremely large loop. The following is my attempt as a Rcpp to speed it up.

## Toy-Data

```
synthetic_LMsummary<-lapply(1:100000L,function(UU){summary(lm(rnorm(500)~replicate(2,{rnorm(500)})))})
```

## R Version

```
tidy.train <- function(s,SelectedRow=3) {

  out<-data.frame(
                  estimate=s$coefficients[, "Estimate"][SelectedRow],
                  std.error=s$coefficients[, "Std. Error"][SelectedRow],
                  statistic=s$coefficients[, "t value"][SelectedRow],
                  p.value=s$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"][SelectedRow],
                  rsquared=s$r.squared
                 )
 row.names(out) <- NULL
out
}

synthetic_LMsummary %>% purrr::map_dfr(~tidy.train(.,SelectedRow=3))
```

## Attempted Rcpp Version

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='

 #include <Rcpp.h>

 // [[Rcpp::export]]

 using namespace std;
 using namespace Rcpp;

 Rcpp::NumericMatrix RcppTidy(Rcpp::List Summary_List,int mat_cols, int select) {
 int mat_rows = Summary_List.length();
 Rcpp::NumericMatrix Output_Mat(mat_rows,mat_cols);

 for (int i = 0; i < Summary_List.length(); ++i) {
      Rcpp::List SubSet=Summary_List[i];
      Rcpp::NumericMatrix CoefDF=SubSet["coefficients"];
      Rcpp::NumericVector Coef=CoefDF.row(select);
      Rcpp::NumericVector rsquared=SubSet["adj.r.squared"];
      Output_Mat(i,_) = cbind(Coef,rsquared);
  }
  return Output_Mat;
 }

')


Tidy_synLM<-RcppTidy(synthetic_LMsummary,5L,3L)
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to extract?

Comment: I assume something like `f <- function(x, i) c(x[[4L]][i,], x[[9L]])` is not appropriate (why not..?)

Comment: Basically each element in the list is a summary.lm object.  I extract estimate-, std.error, statistic, p.value, rsquared for each element of said list and bind the final looped result into a data.frame. The R version works well but I was trying to speed it up via Rcpp

Comment: @DonaldSeinen's version is 18x faster than the question's. Can Rcpp perform Donald's 3 extraction operations in significantly faster time?

Comment: Good point. Probably not.

Comment: Why compute the whole summary if you just need the information regarding the second coefficient and R^2? why NOT extract that information when building your models. In that case you do not have to loop again

Comment: Also do you already have the list? or are you creating the list AND extracting the information?

Comment: The list already exists. So Mapping {f <- function(x, i) c(x[[4L]][i,], x[[9L]])} makes the most sense